# starts with over an array

Tags: c#, linq

I have a function like so

```
public List<Entry> GetEntriesForSlider(int first, int max, List<string> NameLetters)
{
    //Some code
}
```

Inside this code, I want to search along a database, to return every result that has the firstname starting with a letter within the NameLetters.

So if I pass in the array `NameLetters = ["a","b","c"]`

Then it will return results such as

```
Amy 
Bert 
Aaron 
Chris
```

It should be noted that I am ideally looking to use some sort of linq statement such as...

```
entries.Where(x => x.FirstName.StartsWith(partofArray));
```

If at all possible.

EDIT : I previously had the following :

```
var entries = _repository.All<Entry>().Skip(first).Take(max);
if (NameLetters != null && NameLetters.Count > 0)
    entries = entries.Where(x => NameLetters.Contains(x.FirstName[0].ToString()));
```

But what I found was, it enumerated the query (I think) before running the where statement. Possibly because trying to access the first letter of firstname (Or the ToString).

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Comment: Are you planning on using `EntityFramework` or just `SQL Connections` ?

Comment: Do you want to take the page of data _that meets your condition_ or the ones out of that meet that condition out of a page?

Comment: The program with the original query is that NameLetters. Contains cannot be translated to a store query since that array isn't known to the store.

Answer (score 3):

If you're just looking to match the first letter try:

```
entries.Where(x => partofArray.Contains(x.FirstName[0]));
```

If you need to worry about null or empty strings a safer version would be:

```
entries.Where(x => 
                  !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.FirstName) &&
                  partofArray.Contains(x.FirstName[0])
             );
```

If you want to use variable-length strings try:

```
entries.Where(x => 
                   partofArray.Any( p=> x.FirstName.StartsWith(p))
             );
```

Comment: Had an issue with this, will edit question. EDIT, Also your second one seems to enumerate the query aswell I think :\

Comment: When you say "enumerate the query" you mean execute the actual SQL?

Comment: I mean it will fetch the data first, then run the Where statement on the returned data set, instead of writing a LIKE statement to the DB.

Comment: No, I think the OP means that since partOfArray isn't known to the SQL server it can't be joined by EF at the store level, the whole object set would have to be returned and filtered by the client app afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should take a look at [predicate builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx).

Then something like

```
IQueryable<Entry> GetThingsThatBeginWithA(String[] prefixes)
{
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Entry>();
    foreach (String prefix in prefixes)
        predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.FirstName.StartsWith(prefix));
    return database.Entries.Where(predicate);
}
```

This query should correctly compile to a single query to the SQL store.

Update: It can also be done without predicate builder, but I find that working with expression trees without it is really tedious.